# Отличие несогласованного определения от дополнения

Tags: пунктуация

1. Как отличить несогласованное определение от дополнения? В школе раньше в таких случаях делали двойное подчёркивание, например: мебель(какая? из чего?) из берёзы (подчёркивали как дополнение и как определение). А как быть, когда от того дополнением является член предложения или определением зависит постановка запятой? Например: 1. *Изделие (какое?) из древесины первого сорта, (какое?) круглой формы* (в данном, случае, если я правильно понимаю, определения из древесины и круглой формы являются однородными, поэтому между ними ставится запятая); 2. *Изделие (из чего?) из древесины первого сорта (какое?) круглой формы* (между дополнением и определением запятая не ставится. В каком из этих примеров правильно расставлены знаки препинания? Почему? Как отличить несогласованное определение от дополнения? (По поводу того, что определение указывает на признак, а дополнение на объект, и что можно заменить несогласованное определение (с целью точно установить определением оно является или нет) на согласованное, я знаю, хотелось бы узнать о других критериях (вопрос возник потому что встречала оба варианта: и с запятой и без неё).
2. Вслед за первым вопросом возникает ещё один: в словосочетании *поворот налево* слово *налево* выполняет функцию определения или обстоятельства: поворот (куда?) налево; поворот (какой?) налево.

Comment: Сведите к одному-двум вопросам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В вопросе (1)** неясная семантика: речь идет о круглом изделии или о цельной древесине круглой формы, из которой сделано это изделие? Соответственно, сложно выбрать правильный вариант.

Здесь, скорее всего, надо рассматривать тему  **об однородных и неоднородных определениях** (а не о дополнении и определении). Определения могут рассматриваться как неоднородные, так как обозначают разные признаки (сорт древесины и форму), но могут рассматриваться как однородные со сближенными признаками, дающими общую характеристику изделия. **Поэтому оба варианта возможны**, но надо разобраться с неясным смыслом.

Вообще говоря, различать определения и дополнения **можно различными способами**. Определение задает предмету существенный, качественный признак/знак, по которому его можно отличить от других предметов (шкатулка ручной работы), а дополнение дополняет  предмет различными связями (письмо брату). Можно отличить по вопросу, который больше подходит: письмо (кому) брату - только дополнение, шкатулка (какая) ручной работы, дом (какой, из чего) - определительное дополнение или объектное определение. Можно отличить по соотношению с глаголом: директор руководит заводом - директор завода (дополнение).

**Вопрос (2).** Повернуть (куда?) направо (обстоятельство), поворот (куда?) направо (обстоятельственное определение).